# How to find and correct date not in correct format from dataset in python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

my csv dataset has date column as datatype= object. I have to change that to date time. to do so i use the following code.

`train=pd.read_csv(r"C:\train.csv")`

`train['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(train.Date,format='%Y-%d-%m')`

This gives me error as below

`ValueError: unconverted data remains: 2`

It looks like 2 of these data might not be in actual order eg. may be 2020-02-14, is as 2020-14-02 or so.
I have 17000 rows and manually it is impossible to catch 2 data.

Question is how do I correct it ? How to find which data is creating problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check these rows by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `errors='coerce'` for missing values for no matched vals, test it by [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = train[pd.to_datetime(train.Date,format='%Y-%d-%m', errors='coerce').isna()]
print (df)
```

Comment: Thanks, Doing testing, however after isna(), records are too large to figure out. Need to do lot of filtering. The problem is record are there but not sure why not getting converted. The reason need to fin. But thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: @Udaymishra - Do you think many columns? Or many wrong datetimes?

Comment: I didn't understand question, but I have one column "Date" where value error saying 2 data not converted.

Comment: @Udaymishra - I only react for `records are too large to figure out.` So ask if resolve it.